# How to install VirtualBox on Kubuntu 12.04 with lts-raring hardware enablement stack?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 with the lts-raring hardware enablement stack. When I first installed the lts-raring hardware enablement stack I had problems with virtualbox but I resolved those (see "Background" below). However, a recent update caused new and more severe problems. Whenever I try to start a virtual machine at the moment the virtual machine boots into the GUI, my entire system (the host OS) crashes (it instantly reboots without warning).

In researching this I see the following bug report:

Bug #1127101 “Installing LTSEnablementStack in Ubuntu 12.04.2 breaks VirtualBox”
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1127101

> Temporary workaround : uninstall Virtualbox and install Virtualbox-4.2
>   from Oracle repositories. See here for instructions :
>   http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/virtualbox.org_contrib?dist=precise

Is that the best solution or the recommended approach? Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Here's some system info:

```
$ uname -r
3.8.0-30-lowlatency

$ dpkg -s virtualbox
Package: virtualbox
Status: install ok installed
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3
```

## Background:

How I initially resolved the problem:

Comment #13 : Bug #1076603 : Bugs : “virtualbox-guest kernel module fails to build on 3.7.0 kernel”
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1076603/comments/13

wget -O /tmp/virtualbox.patch 'http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=99;filename=vbox-wheezy.patch;att=1;bug=696011'
cd /usr/src/virtualbox-4.1.12/
patch -p4 < /tmp/virtualbox.patch
dkms autoinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chatted with VirtualBox devs on IRC and they told me that Ubuntu does not regularly accept bug fixes from the VirtualBox devs. They recommended that I install the latest VirtualBox package from virtualbox.org, which I did. **That solved the problem.**

The download link for Linux is:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

It is actually a simpler install because you don't need to install guest additions separately. Uninstall the Ubuntu virtualbox packages using apt-get remove or purge.